# mysql how to find median from even number of rows

Tags: mysql

Found some solution in StackOverflow and other websites to find median but all of them works with the following principal- median is the row for which half of the number of rows is less and it and other half is greater. But for even number of rows, the median is the average of two middle values. How to calculate it in MySQL?

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MySQL version  5.7.25

Answer (score 1):

Given the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  i INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  n INT,
  INDEX(n)
);
```

We want to find the median of column `n`.

### ROW_NUMBER() & CTE (Requires MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2)

```
with sorted as (
    select t.n, row_number() over (order by t.n) as rn
    from numbers t
), cnt as (
    select count(*) as c from numbers
)
select avg(s.n) as median
from sorted s
cross join cnt
where s.rn between floor((c+1)/2) and ceil((c+1)/2);
```

Performance: OK (140ms for 100K rows)

### Temporary table with AUTO_INCREMENT

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp(
    rn int auto_increment primary key,
    n int
) engine=memory;

insert into tmp(n) 
    select n
    from numbers
    order by n;

select avg(n) as median
from tmp
cross join (select count(*) as c from numbers) cnt
where rn between floor((c+1)/2) and ceil((c+1)/2);
```

Performance: OK (110ms for 100K rows)

### Prepared statement with calculated LIMIT/OFFSET

```
set @c = (select count(*) from numbers);
set @limit = 2 - (@c % 2);
set @offset = (@c+1) div 2 - 1;

prepare stmt from '
    select avg(n) as median
    from (
        select n
        from numbers
        limit ? offset ?
    ) sub
';

execute stmt using @limit, @offset;
```

Performance: Best (50ms for 100K rows)

### CROSS JOIN

#### Using primary key

```
select avg(n) as median
from (
  select t.n
  from numbers t
  cross join numbers t2
  group by t.i
  having greatest(sum(t2.n < t.n), sum(t2.n > t.n))
      <= (select count(*) from numbers) / 2
) sub
```

#### Without primary key

```
select avg(n) as median
from (
    select t.n
    from numbers t
    cross join numbers t2
    group by t.n
    having greatest(sum(t2.n < t.n), sum(t2.n > t.n)) / sqrt(SUM(t2.n = t.n))
        <= (select count(*) from numbers)/2
) sub
```

Performance: Worst - O(n²) (500ms for 1K rows)